# Office 365 integration with web app

Tags: azure, office365

I want to know how I can edit documents hosted on my website with Office 365 integration and it directly saves back to my server? How dropbox achieved this ?

I already have my api which provides access to files hosted on my server with oauth. I have searched a lot online about Office 365 integrations it looks like I can edit and access the stuff hosted on Azure/Microsoft services like calendars,contacts,docs etc.. I am unable to figure out if there is way I can send my document to office 356 and through api it edits my document and saves back to my server ?

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I'm looking at doing. We have a we app that stores files on Azure cloud. We'd like to use Office 365 to edit the Word and Excel docs online, without leaving our app, just like Dropbox does it. Until I saw it on Dropbox I didn't think it was possible. Have you come up with a solution? I would love to hear it if you have.

Comment: No progress mate yet

Comment: @Glaucus - I understand that this is an old thread but have you tried wopi - https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. It's meant for document based app integration

Comment: @Andy, Thanks. I'm no longer working on that project, but if I get back to it, I'll take a look. Thanks.